# Migrate Laravel User and Password table to Django

Tags: php, django, laravel, hash, passwords

I just want to know how can i migrate the users and passwords that is made with laravel 5.8 to a fresh django application. i searched for some answers how to decrpyt the password back to plain text so i can encrypt/hash the password to the technology that django uses. if you have different approach just reply to the thread. Thank you.

Comment: you can't 'decrypt' them because they are not encrypted, they are hashed, which is one way

Comment: hi, is there any other way to migrate it to a fresh django application? or is there a library for django that is the same way laravel hashes it's password?

Comment: laravel uses bcrypt

Comment: Hi! thank you. i will find a way how to use it on django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel default password hashing algorithm is [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). Just [configure Django to use it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/#using-bcrypt-with-django) and you should be fine.